# 404 not found angular 2 routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I keep getting the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/app.routes
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/app.routes as "./app.routes" from http://localhost:4200/main.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/app.routes(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/app.routes(…)
```

This is my app.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component'
import { CreateServiceComponent } from './app/createservice/createservice.component'

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  //{ path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisCenterComponent },
  { path: 'services/create', component: CreateServiceComponent },
  { path: '/', component: AppComponent }
  //{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

and my main.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    RouterModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CreateServiceComponent ],
  providers: [ appRoutingProviders ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent,FIREBASE_PROVIDERS ]
})
export class MyAppModule {}

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
  defaultFirebase(firebaseConfig),
  firebaseAuthConfig({
  provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
  method: AuthMethods.Popup
})]);
```

Comment: Seems as a path issue for app.routes file, http://localhost:4200/app.routes, did you check if the file is present at the location?

Comment: Got this working now but can't seem to get the router link to link anywhere keep getting a template error when I use [routerLink] on an anchor tag. If you want to submit an answer I'll accept it since this was the issue

Comment: Please add respective code to look into it.

Comment: Made a new question for this since its a different issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128378/angular-2-rc5-template-parse-error?noredirect=1#comment65602895_39128378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as a path issue for app.routes file, localhost:4200/app.routes, did you check if the file is present at the location?

Comment: I moved the app.routes.ts file to the /app directory and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You're combining rc4 logic with rc5 logic...

`NgModule` came with rc5 but the bootstrap method you're using is still rc4.

You need to change how you're bootstrapping your application to something like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
// or wherever your AppModule lives
import AppModule from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Getting errors when I do this platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyAppModule) instead of what I have

Comment: In that case, I believe you have a build or configuration issue... you will need to post that information as part of your question please.